# Cosa significa "avveduta" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti,  la pittrice Artemisia Gentileschi dice queste parole descrivendo il comportamento di una sua conoscente, Giovanna:

> Si trattava da dama, aveva denaro e gioielli, comandava a suon di zuccherini la suocera golosa. Smaniava di grandezze, per quattro passi volle accompagnarmi a casa in carrozza; mi venne dietro per la scala a curiosare, mi entrò sino in camera. Io mi sentivo **avveduta** come una matrona e la lasciavo fare.

Ho cercato il significato del verbo "avvedersi" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che significa accorgersi, rendersi conto, prendere coscienza di qualcosa. Tuttavia non riesco a capire cosa significa che Artemisia si sentiva "avveduta". Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'aggettivo *avveduto* significa "scaltro, accorto, giudizioso, prudente" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avveduto/), e indica qualcuno che sa come comportarsi in certe situazioni. Credo che qui si voglia dire che Artemisia sa come trattare Giovanna, e la lascia curiosare.

Answer (score 2):

In questo caso può significare che la sua tranquillità nel lasciarla fare e il non preoccuparsi derivino da un saper veder lucidamente la situazione, con intelligenza: come di una persona esperta o di una persona appunto, con esperienza, come una matrona che era la signora della casa e che dell'alto dei suoi anni  è in grado di aiutare e consigliare, un pò come fanno le nonne, che danno conforto davanti ai problemi, proprio perché avvedute della vita e consepevoli che tutto si risolve.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Alessandro, e grazie mille della risposta!